# VIM version 8.2.1847 problems on 22.04: can't delete backspace and changelist not saved

Tags: command-line, vim

After installing 22.04 I have two VIM problems:

1. I can't backspace over a newline!  If you insert "abc<*newline*>d" then begin backspacing to delete the new text it stops at the newline and won't remove it and continue deleting the first "abc" line.
2. If I edit a file then save and exit, when I edit the file again "g;" no longer moves to the previous (last) change.  It gives the error "E664: changelist is empty" now.

Both of these worked fine with the VIM that was on my old 18.04 install.  How do I get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 0):

I added `set backspace=indent,eol,start` to `.vimrc` (which wasn't needed before) and backspace is working properly now.

Turns out the vim that came with my minimum 22.04 installation had reduced features and was the source of both problems.  There's nothing on the vim startup screen that indicates this but :version would have revealed it.  I had thought the minimum installation just included fewer applications, but at least with vim you get a version with reduced functionality.  A `sudo apt-get install vim` got me the complete vim and fixed both problems.